# Ionic, v1.0.0-beta.14 does not support ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I was trying to use ui-calendar in my Ionic App . However I was getting this error ,

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Scope.link.scope.init (calendar.js:226)
at Object.fn (calendar.js:262)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22020)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:22282)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:17439)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:17629)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:17570)
```

Using a previous version however runs it as seen in the following plunkr . http://plnkr.co/edit/zfKkCp2pMaeDGvN3rq86?p=preview

How do I solve this . Please help .

Comment: Have you included `fullcalendar.js` in your index.html? For some reason your plunkr is not opening for me right now.

Comment: That plunker shows a working example but with previous version of ionic . Yes I have included fullcalendar.js .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed some versions from the used libraries and now the plunker works on `ionic beta 14`.

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/aYXBJ0Ll2Q4xMYBgkiTo?p=preview